# Problem using Java standard library in C# with IKVM

Tags: c#, java, mono, ikvm

I'm trying to use java.util.List in a C# file. I have IKVM 0.40. I try to use the java.util namespace like this

```
using IKVM.OpenJDK.Util;
```

and compile the file (test.cs) with Mono like this

```
mcs -reference:/path/to/IKVM.OpenJDK.Util.dll,path/to/IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll,path/to/IKVM.Runtime.dll test.cs
```

but I get the following error

```
The type or namespace name `OpenJDK' does not exist in the namespace `IKVM'.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace is java.util that you need to use:

```
using java.util;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use -L instead of using -reference.

Comment: Doesn't fix anything. What should I pass with -L?

Comment: I'm using lib instead of reference (because -L is deprecated in the version of mcs I have) and it doesn't even find IKVM, let alone IKVM.OpenJDK